# Ceramic capacitors in parallel. Is this configuration suitable?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor

I am building a circuit based on an ATmega328P. In the schematic of the datasheet are 3 capacitors (1uF, 4.7uF polarized, 1uF) in parallel on the power supply Vcc. I assume these are for decoupling purpose.

[image: snippet from schematic diagram]

I currently only have 470nF ceramic film capacitors (805) and tantalum capacitors (805). Is it possible to connect 2x470nF in *parallel* to achieve the ~1uF on the respective lines? In theory the capacitance is 940nF, but since it is used for decoupling it might be bad for the signal, because I solder two parts instead of one (more solder, cables, cable length, more resistance, ...).

Does this matter in a practical situation?

EDIT: I build the circuit on a hole grid breadboard

Comment: Do not forget that capacitors add in parallel and not in series.

Comment: My mistake. I changed it the desired situation. Thanks

Comment: However, I think it does not really matter. A simple 470nF shoud be enough because your microcontroller does not draw a lot of current.

Comment: The VCC and AVCC pins should be decoupled independently, they are very far away from each other: place a small cap (10–100 nF) close to *each* supply pin.

Comment: As a courtesy and good practice, please have your decoupling capacitors facing up/down and ground pointing downwards. Drawing common circuit elements in an unusual way obfuscates the meaning of your circuit, which defeats the entire purpose of the schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this matter in a practical situation?

**NO**, one capacitor of more than 100 nF is usually already enough in 99.99% of all situations.

Place the capacitor as close to the VCC pins as possible.

There is really **no need** to place more than one 1 uF ceramic capacitor.

There is **no point** to combine decoupling or bypass capacitors such that they have a certain value.

Learn more about bypass capacitors by watching [the EEVBlog video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcJ6UdDx1vg&t=0).

> EDIT: I build the circuit on a hole grid breadboard

When using a breadboard, connections are so bad (due to contact resistance) anyway that it really doesn't matter what capacitor values you use.

Comment: Why are there 3 capacitors in the datasheet? And explicit a polarized one? They must have some function

Comment: When the circuit is working I will commission a PCB where the connections are much better

Comment: @v3xX Either inexperienced designer or that is the only Vcc bulk capacitor on the board. If the latter, you should avoid drawing like that to avoid these questions.

Comment: @winny I do not understand. This is the only polarized capacitor between the main power line (5V) and the rest of the circuit

Comment: *Why are there 3 capacitors in the datasheet?* Because the chip has **3 VCC/AVCC pins** each pin gets its own capacitor. The polarized capacitor has a larger value and also a "buffer" for energy. A non-polarized capacitor with the same capacitance is larger and more expensive. There are **many** things that (experienced) designers do in certain ways because these ways have been proven to work. Just follow their lead, do what they do. You might not always fully understand **but that does not matter**. Your circuit is non-critical, add a capacitor here and there and it will just work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This does makes sense. I will place the ceramic C (with the right value) close to the Vcc pin and the polarized at the entry point of the +5V rail since it decouples the whole circuit. Is this the correct approach

Comment: Yes that is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @v3xX Remove the word polarized. Are these three the only capacitors from Vcc to ground?

Comment: No. Almost every chip I use has some sort of decoupling capacitor (either normal or polarized).

Comment: @v3xX Please include @ and username or he/she will not be notified. Polarized to me sounds electrolytic or tantal, neither of which I would call suitable for decupling. Try to keep all your bulk (tantal/electrolytic) as a part of your power supply part/page of the schematic and a 100 nF ceramic for each decoupling unless stated otherwise by the datasheet.